# How can I use the terminal name for the ICA login in IGEL UMS?

Tags: linux, terminal

I have several IGEL UD3 Linux thin clients, and I am using the IGEL Universal Management Suite (UMS) to manage them. Right now, I have to define a separate profile for every terminal because each terminal uses a different login name for it's Citrix ICA connection. If I could use the terminal name for the login name, then I would only need to create one profile. When I was using WYSE thin clients with WNOS, I could put `$TN` in the username field and it would get replaced with the terminal name. Is there a way to do this in IGEL UMS?

Answer (score 0):

1. In the profile settings, under System → Firmware Customization → Custom Commands → Reconfiguration Commands, copy and paste this command.

   ```
   sed -i~ "s/\$TN/`hostname`/g" /userhome/.ICAClient/appsrv.ini
   ```

   [image: Custom Commands Settings]
2. After that, you can put the value `$TN` in your ICA user name field, and it will get replaced with the terminal name.

   [image: ICA Connection Settings]